# Boundary for coefficients of a complex polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

prove that if $ f(z) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^m a_k z^k, ~~ \sup\limits_{|z| = 1} |f(z)| = M $, then $ \sum\limits_{k=0}^m |a_k|^2 \leq 2 \pi M^2$

I don't really know how to get into the problem - usually all inequalities of such type are in the direction that I'm not seeking.

I would appreciate some help

Comment: typo: "coefficients"

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hint: write $f(e^{i\theta}) = \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^m a_k e^{ik\theta}$ so that $$|f(e^{i\theta})|^2 = \sum_{j,k=0}^m a_k \bar a_j e^{i(k-j)\theta}.$$
If $k-j \not= 0$ then $\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} e^{i(k-j)\theta} \, d\theta = 0$ so that $$\int_0^{2\pi} |f(e^{i\theta})|^2 \, d\theta =2\pi \sum_{k=0}^m |a_k|^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

Since Umberto P. 's answer:
$$\int_0^{2\pi} |f(e^{i\theta})|^2 \, d\theta \le \int_0^{2\pi} M^2 d\theta = 2\pi.M^2.$$
But
the right-side is $2\pi \sum_{k=0}^m |a_k|^2.$ So $\sum_{k=0}^m |a_k|^2 \le M^2$, not $2\pi.M^2$. The question of Jytug is wrong?